# DataError: unterminated CSV quoted field

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, csv, psycopg2

I'm trying to import a huge (~2 GB) csv file into postgres. Below is the query I wrote (in Python) to do this:

```
q= ("COPY {db} from '{d}\\{file}' WITH (FORMAT CSV, NULL 'NULL', HEADER)
 ;").format(d = directory, db = db_name, file =fname)
```

Now somewhere on line `17632150`there is an *Integer* field that starts with a quotation, which is also not closed:

```
 "2195961,12855,628,No
```

I wonder what my options are at this point? My only constraint is that it should be possible to do this with `psycopg2`.

Comment: Is it safe to remove all quotes?  I know that sounds like a bad idea, but I had to ask.  If so, there is a simple solution, assuming you are >= 9.3 and some form of *nix

Comment: your data file is corrupt.  it may contain other invisible corruption too.  if you want to ignore this and use the probably corrupt data my best guess would be that as `"` is 0x22 and `2` is 0x32 the best move is probably to assume one of the bits got toggled randomly somehow and replace the `"` with a `2`

Comment: The quotation mark in Microsoft Excel is normally a formatting thing where it shows the data towards the right rather than the left. So that may also be the issue.